# GCP Python - Google TeamDrive API - Permissions

Tags: python, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-directory-api, google-drive-shared-drive

Would really appreciate some advice while working with the Permissions part of the Google Team Drive API:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions

I am currently writing a piece of code which will Create a team drive, create some files (mimetype folder) to the teamdrive by the ID and then adding a user to the Team Drive as a group.

The code is successfully creating a Team Drive and Folders for each using the API, however, when I add a User to the team drive my response is completely different, for example:

```
def build_google_teamdrive(drive_name):
credentials = get_credentials()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

team_drive_metadata = {'name': drive_name, "colorRgb": "#004e37"}
request_id = str(uuid.uuid4())

response = service.teamdrives().create(body=team_drive_metadata, requestId=request_id).execute()
logger.info('Creating Team Drive for: {}'.format(drive_name))
print(response)
return response
```

This returns a expected response of:

```
{u'kind': u'drive#teamDrive', u'id': u'0AFlsLbuvuChJUk9PVA', u'name': u'TeamDriveName'}
```

This confirms that the code has run expected, same with the .files().

Now when I try to do add a member (group) to a Team Drive, I am getting something totally different:

```
def test_insert():
viewer_group = 'some_user@test.domain.co.uk'
drive_unique_id = '0BKk5OjdX66ooUk9PVA'
credentials = get_credentials()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

resource = {
    "role": "reader",
    "type": "group",
    "emailAddress": viewer_group
}

response = service.permissions().create(fileId=drive_unique_id, body=resource, supportsTeamDrives=True, sendNotificationEmail=False)
print(response)
return response
```

This returns the response:

```
<googleapiclient.http.HttpRequest object at 0x104e741d0>
```

When using the Permissions Insert API : The response I am expecting was:

```
{"kind": "drive#permission","id": "00723864391275245674","type": "group","role": "reader"}
```

If I could get any help regarding this problem I would be really appreciative as I am really baffled how it is not working.

Thanks,
**PyJordan**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code it is quite clear why the response did not return as expected, please look here:

```
response = service.teamdrives().create(body=team_drive_metadata, requestId=request_id).execute()
```

As you can see at the end of the response, you have wrote:

```
.execute()
```

The fix is simple, in your code you have wrote:

```
response = service.permissions().create(fileId=drive_unique_id, body=resource, supportsTeamDrives=True, sendNotificationEmail=False)
```

I will now fix this for you:

```
response = service.permissions().create(fileId=drive_unique_id, body=resource, supportsTeamDrives=True, sendNotificationEmail=False).execute()
```

Hope this helps and goodluck.

VS

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly! Seems like it has been a long day! Upvoted!